# find elements for list in string

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string, 'RTKLOANGMSTTTS' and a list of tuples, [(2,5),(8,9)], that returns a string containing the letters 2-5 and 8-9 both inclusive, that is 'TKLOGM'.
I was thinking something like:

```
def f(string, lst):
    for element in lst:
        if element in string:
            print string
```

But it does not return anything?

Comment: So, you want to slice the string with the tuples in the list? If thats what you need, it's pretty easy in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
def f(source, lst):
    return "".join(source[start - 1:end] for start, end in lst)
```

What this will do is iterate over the `lst`, extracting the tuple into `start` and `end` on every iteration. Then it will create a new string as a slice from the `source` string, from `start - 1` to `end` (we use `start - 1` because you showed that 1 means the first character, but python uses 0-indexing, so we must substract one). Finally we join all the strings using `"".join()`.

If you use an older version of Python that doesn't support the generator syntax, use this instead:

```
def f(source, lst):
    return "".join([source[start - 1:end] for start, end in lst])
```

It works exactly the same, but instead of working with a generator it explicitly creates a list which gets joined.

Comment: that will not give the answer needed by OP, you will have `KLOAMS`, not `TKLOGM`....

Comment: @Cédric Julien: Woops, I thought the OP was sane and used 0-indexing. I'll fix this.

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the error:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: @LinusSvendsson: How are you using the function? It should be used like this: `result = f("RTKLOANGMSTTTS", [(2,5),(8,9)])`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x = 'RTKLOANGMSTTTS'
>>> l = [(2,5),(8,9)]
>>> ''.join(x[s-1:e] for (s,e) in l)
'TKLOGM'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you asking for. I can't test right now, but try:

```
def f(string, lst):
    getStr = ''
    for t in lst:
        begin, end = t
        getStr += string[begin-1:end]
    return getStr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(string, lst):
   for start, end in lst:
       s = string[start-1:end]
       if s:
           yield s

for s in f('RTKLOANGMSTTTS', [(2,5),(8,9)]):
    print s
```